# sql result with numbers as column headers, how to call with with PHP or change sql column headers for pivot

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a pivot table that outputs the following result set:
[image]

as you can see column names are 0.9,1.2,1.5 etc etc

in my php, I cant reference the number

```
echo  $order->a;
```

I get error:`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE`

How can I correctly fetch this column or perhaps adjust the sql to have an alias? like a or b? like:

```
select * from t pivot ( avg(stock) for length in ([0.9] as a, [1.2] as b)) piv
```

Thanks as always,

Comment: Use other aliases in that pivot query or theres lots of room for confusion down the road.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have the ability to alter those horrible column names in any way shape or form?

Comment: correct. what other options do I have? the pivot doesn't work with alias's and to create a case statement for this wont be very manageable.

Comment: Have your tried this notation: [databasename].[dbo].[some_table].[sometimesacolumngoeshere]?

Comment: that is what I currently have. `[0.9], [1.2], [1.5], [1.8]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alias your columns then you would have to use something like the following, where you place your alias in the final select list:

```
select section, 
  [0.9] as a,
  [1.2] as b
from t 
pivot 
( 
  avg(stock) 
  for length in ([0.9], [1.2])
) piv
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah only way around it. had to go write a 25 line case statement but working now. thanks.